# Как с помощью словаря REST выразить такие действия?

Tags: веб-программирование, rest

1) Действие отмены заказа?

POST /api/v1/order/1/cancel
- В этом случае создается новый ресурс действия отмены заказов, после такого RESTful его уже нельзя назвать

PATCH /api/v1/order/1
{
"status": "cancel"
}
- В этом случае вместе со статусом могут быть переданы любые другие параметры, это усложняет валидацию ролевого доступа

2) Действие создания запроса верификации?

POST /api/v1/user/1/verification/request?

(этим действием клиент загружает документ, необходимый для верификации профиля)

3) Действие создания запроса на восстановление пароля?

POST /api/v1/user/1/password/reset?

У меня когнитивный диссонанс в этом вопросе, где почитать на эту тему?

Comment: 1 - DELETE /api/v1/order/:id (у вас же нет физического удаления, и отмена максимально совпадает с этим действием, верно)? И было бы хорошо уточнить, что такое запрос верификации

Comment: А не нарушается ли таким образом, принцип идемпотентности? дополнил

Comment: А если DELETE /api/v1/order/:id уже есть и он означает именно удаление?

Comment: Нет, не наршуается (нельзя отменить заказ несколько раз); заказы не подразумевают физического удаления в принципе, только "закрытие".

Comment: 2. Вы используете методы (глаголы) в методе - reset в post. Это противоречит стилю rest. Если вы хотите что-то запросить, то почему не использовать GET? Посмотрите здесь: http://art-in-stamps.ru/development/restful-web-services.shtml

Comment: Касательно 2-го пункта: таким запросом я хочу зафиксировать в БД запись о загрузке клиентом документа, т.е. данные я не запрашиваю, значит это точно не GET, верно?